# Teradata Error 2665: Invalid Date

Tags: teradata, invalidation, error-code

I am issuing the following SELECT on SQLA (Teradata version: 15.10.01.11):

```
select cast('2018-05-31' as date format 'yyyy-mm-dd') - interval '6' month;
```

And I am getting: SELECT Failed. 2665: Invalid Date.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Br,

Shardul

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to Standard SQL subtracting 6 months from `2018-05-31` results in `2017-11-31` which obviously doesn't exist.

Interval arithmetic can't be used for month/years (Feb 29th), better use `ADD_MONTHS`:

```
ADD_MONTHS(DATE '2018-05-31', -6)
```

There also `oADD_MONTHS`, which might return a different result for months end dates, e.g.

```
ADD_MONTHS(DATE '2017-11-30', 6)  -> 2018-05-30
oADD_MONTHS(DATE '2017-11-30', 6) -> 2018-05-31
```

Comment: Thank you Dieter! I found the issue after some research. Appreciate your kind help. I will be using ADD_MONTHS instead of INTERVAL until and unless I am sure that INTERVAL is not violating any date constraints. Thanks again.

Comment: Hi Dieter, I noticed one more thing with `INTERVAL`. This issue of `INVALID` date occurs only when we are adding or subtracting `MONTH` as `INTERVAL` from a particular date. I did not come across this issue while adding or subtracting `DAY` as `INTERVAL` from any date.

Comment: Of course, you can't get an invalid date for `DAY`, but unless you got a Timestamp you can simply use old style `dateCol +1`. And `interval year` usually fails in a leap year, trying to add one year to Feb 29th :-)

Comment: Sorry @dnoeth, I did not understand the 2nd part of the first line "but unless you got a Timestamp you can simply use old style `dateCol +1`".

Comment: If you got a Date you can simply use +/- number_of_days (`current_date -1` for yesterday, no need for `INTERVAL '1' DAY`), but this doesn't work for Timestamps

Comment: Oh ok! Thank you so much for all the help! :-)